# Что означает if r, err := f1(i); err != nil в GoLang?

Tags: golang

Даже незнаю, как нагуглить (подобное нашел только в if, все равно не получилось въехать). Объясните, пожалуйста, что означает в этих местах **err** и как в переменных перед err появляется значение, присвоенное err:
1. `src, err := os.Open(srcName, os.O_RDONLY, 0)`
2. `if r, err := f1(i); err != nil`
Подобная конструкция наблюдалась и с ok вмеcто err.
В документации нашел такое:

```
if v := math.Pow(x, n); v < lim {
        return v
    }
```

Однако тут все понятно, в отличие от примеров выше.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Там происходит примерно то же самое, что вы нашли в документации, на это просто дополнительно наложились [**множественный возврат** и **множественное присваивание**](https://gobyexample.com/multiple-return-values). **"Значение" (на деле не одно) присваивается не в `err`, а раскладывается (по кусочкам) по всему списку переменных.**

Вот пример использования этой особенности языка с Go By Example с вольно переведёнными комментариями:

```java
package main

import "fmt"
// (int, int) описывает возвращаемое значение как "два значения типа int"
func vals() (int, int) {
    return 3, 7
}
func main() {
    // Два значения разошлись по разным переменным, вот множественное присваивание
    a, b := vals()
    fmt.Println(a)
    fmt.Println(b)

    // Неиспользуемые значения можно присвоить в пустоту, обозначаемую _
    _, c := vals()
    fmt.Println(c)
}
```

У вас то же самое, просто типы другие.

Answer (score 3):

Если вы посмотрите в документацию, то там дано следующее описание

```
func Open(name string) (*File, error)
```

Это описание говорит, что функция возвращает тип из 2 значений. Первое это собственно файл, а второе - это ошибка. Оператор присваивания деконструирует этот тип в 2 переменные.

Более простой пример использования оператора присваивания можете посмотреть и запустить [тут](https://play.golang.org/p/KbKuLi0W6O). Вот его полный код.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    a, b := 5, 6
    fmt.Println("a =", a)
    fmt.Println("b =", b)
}
```

После присвоения вы можете проверить переменную в которую помещается ошибка (`err != nil`) и обработать ее.

Comment: И Вам спасибо, и человеку выше. Мог бы - поставил две галки, но так нельзя :)

Comment: главное, что одну поставили.